# Why is MarkLogic Admin Page showing an EvtSocketConnected Message?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

My localhost MarkLogic Admin page (http://localhost:8001) is not rendering.

The web page shows the following xml instead.

```
<EvtSocketConnected xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ReturnCode>0</ReturnCode>
</EvtSocketConnected>
```

I assume that this message is happening because the server is busy merging/balancing forests but I'm not sure.

Is anyone else getting this message?

Could MarkLogic Engineering team provide more info on this?

I'm running MarkLogic version 8.0-5.2

Comment: The ErrorTxt.log is showing forest recovering messages "state changed from recovering to open".

Comment: The good news is that a full reboot fixes the problem. I'd like to know why this is a re-occurring issue for me. It only started happening after I upgraded to version 8.0-5.2.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a similar response on that port when the Cisco Jabber IM client is running.

Comment: Good catch! You are correct. My Cisco Jabber IM client was using port 8001.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause was that another client application was using port 8001.

In my case, it was the Cisco Jabber IM.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucm/port/9_0_1/CUCM_BK_T98E8963_00_tcp-port-usage-guide-90/CUCM_BK_T98E8963_00_tcp-port-usage-guide-90_chapter_01.html

My fix was to turn off Cisco Jabber.